# Regex for match function Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to extract some part of a string and put those in array with Ruby.
I have a string like :

```
test = ["pack_1 (>=5.0.2)", "pack_2", "pack_3", "pack_4 (>=4.3.0)"]
```

I want a regex that works with `match` to extract these parts `(pack_1, pack_2, pack_3, pack_4)` and then I will put them into array. The end result will be something like:

```
[pack_1, pack_2, pack_3, pack_4]
```

Snippet Part :

```
if line.match(/([^\s]+)/).to_s.length > 0
 array << line.match(/[^\s]+.=.\[(.*,)/).to_s // The regex here does not work proparly     
end
```

Comment: Your desired end result is not valid Ruby. (It is syntactically valid, but not semantically, since `pack_1`, `pack_2`, `pack_3`, and `pack_4` are undefined local variables.) Please make sure that your desired output is actually valid, otherwise it is impossible to test an answer for correctness.

Comment: Sorry, I could have make it more clear but I think the desired output should be something like:`["pack_1", "pack_2", "pack_3", "pack_4"]`

Comment: What is the desired result if the string were `'test = ["cat_1 (>=5.0.2)", "pack_2", "dog", "pack", "pack_4 (>=4.3.0)"]'`? You need to state the *rule* employed to obtain the desired result.

Comment: "I have a string like:" should be followed by `'test = ["pack_1 (>=5.0.2)", "pack_2", "pack_3", "pack_4 (>=4.3.0)"]'` (note single quotes I've added) unless you mean "I have an array of strings like:". Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
test = "test = ['Alice (>=5.0.2)', 'John', 'Mike', 'test (>=4.3.0)']"

test.gsub(/\s\(.*?\)/, '')
```

After calling this method variable should be like this

```
"test = ['Alice', 'John', 'Mike', 'test']"
```

Just trim the beginning with slice(7..-1) if you want to get rid of test

```
"['Alice', 'John', 'Mike', 'test']"
```